# How to connect a raspberry pi to a webserver

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, webserver

after some coding I got my raspberry pi to work. So I can control an servo with 2 buttons on html open and close. But this is on a local server (raspberrpiIP:3000) and I want to control the raspberry pi on a live website. So everybody in the world should be able to control it. After much research I couldn't find the right answers to connect my raspberry pi with the script to a live website. This is the script for controlling the servo and connecting to the internet.

```js
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var lockedState = 2200;
var unlockedState = 500;

var motorPin = 14;
var buttonPin = 17;

var app = express();

// *** Start code *** //

var locked = true;

//Setup servo
var Gpio = require(
        motor = new Gpio(motorPin, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
//setup button
button = new Gpio(buttonPin, {mode: Gpio.INPUT,
        pullUpDown: Gpio.PUD_DOWN,
        edge: Gpio.EITHER_EDGE
  }),
  servo = new Gpio(motorPin, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});

button.on('interrupt', function () {
  motor.servoWrite(lockedState);
 setTimeout(function(){motor.servoWrite(0)}, 2000);
});



// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// configure Express to serve index.html and any other static pages stored
// in the home directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname));


//lock rest get call
app.get('/uit', function (req, res) {
        motor.servoWrite(lockedState);
        locked = true;
        res.send('uit')
        console.log('uit gezet')
        //After 1.5 seconds, the door lock servo turns off to avoid stall current
 setTimeout(function(){motor.servoWrite(0)}, 2000);
 });

//unlock rest get call
app.get('/aan', function (req, res){
        motor.servoWrite(unlockedState);
        locked = false;
        res.send('aan')
        console.log('aan gezet')
        //After 1.5 seconds, the door lock servo turns off to avoid stall current
        setTimeout(function(){motor.servoWrite(0)}, 2000)


 });
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Start Express App Server
//
app.listen(3000);
console.log('App Server is listening on port 3000');
```